# Alternate Definition for Limits at Infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Before reading the formal definition of a one-sided limit to infinity, this is what I came up with:

Let f(x) be a function defined on an interval that contains $x = a$. We say that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x) = \inf$ if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta < \epsilon$ and $f(a + \delta) > f(a + \epsilon)$. In other words, no matter how close you get to $a$, you can always get a larger value by going even closer.

Since this definition is different from the official one, I know it must be incorrect. Can you provide an example of a function where this definition would fail?

Comment: Let $f(x) = -x$, $a=0$. Are the conditions of your 'definition' satisfied? (And most importantly, is $\lim_{x \to 0^+} -x = \infty$?)

Comment: This 'definition' seems to state that $f$ is decreasing, without relying on or providing any information on the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your definition.

**First**, you're only requiring $f(a+\delta)$ to be larger than something you already know is a function value. This means that as long as the function only *keeps increasing* as $x$ goes to $a$, you will declare it to have limit $\infty$, even if if there's some bound that it never exceeds. This is what commenter ah11950 was getting at with the example $f(x)=-x$.

**Second**, you're only requiring that there is *one* $\delta$ that makes $f(a+\delta)$ large enough. Your definition doesn't prevent the function from dipping down and becoming small again between $a$ and $a+\delta$. So if you consider $f(x)=\frac1x\sin\frac 1x$, your definition would say that it tends to $\infty$ for $x\to0^+$ -- even though the analogous definition would *also* say that it tends to $-\infty$.